# Yii 2 сортировка Ajax`ом

Tags: yii2

В первой версии сортировка идет при помощи Ajax и браузерная строка не используется

А во второй при сортировке получаю

> http://yii2basic/proj/bonus/index?BonusSearch[id]=&BonusSearch[name]=&BonusSearch[value]=&BonusSearch[attr_id]=1&BonusSearch[desc_]=

что не красиво. как можно включить ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно использовать pjax и отключить pushstate

```
use yii\widgets\Pjax;    

<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'bonus', 'enablePushState' => false]) ?>
<?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,       
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'name',
        'value',
        // 'attr_id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'attr_id',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'label' => 'параметр',
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Attr::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            'value' => 'attr.name'
        ],
        'desc_:ntext',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/